# Heroku custom domain - how to make it so that no one knows it's forwarding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers

I have an app with normal Heroku name (my-app433.heroku.com)

And I've added the custom domain (www.mywebsite.com)

It's simple "forwarding with masking" (`www.mywebsite.com` points to `my-app433.heroku.com` - like Heroku suggests).

But I don't like that when I go to `www.mywebsite.com` - the http headers say `302 Found - my-app433.heroku.com` and then gives all the content.

Is there a way to hide the fact that it's forwarding?

(I'd like to get a simple `200Ok` as if `www.mywebsite.com` is direct domain).

Comment: What type of server is serving the page?

Comment: Webrick - default one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a reason not to, I'd switch from "forwarding with masking" to sending the traffic directly to Heroku using a [CNAME record in your DNS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#dns-setup).

That's how I'm doing it on [my site](http://www.toxinless.com) if you want to compare:

```
> nslookup www.toxinless.com
...
www.toxinless.com   canonical name = toxinless.herokuapp.com.
...

> curl http://www.toxinless.com -I
...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```